# Login not redirecting back to page where login link was clicked if account created

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, redirection

On a Stack Exchange site, if you are viewing a question, and click Log In to take some action on that question, and you log in with valid Stack Exchange credentials (but there's a step that creates an account on that particular site), you are not redirected back to the page on which you clicked the Log In button, that motivated the account creation in the first place.  Instead, it goes to a list of questions on that site, causing the user to lose easy access to what it is they wanted to do.  Even the browser Back button doesn't get the user there for at least a few clicks, going through Document Expired and login pages again.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: It is the right place, although I'm not sure it wasn't asked before.

Comment: Try to click and hold the back button, to jump through the tab history.

Comment: Can you please check if [it's fixed now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261964/login-process-deletes-question/261971?noredirect=1#comment854254_261971)? :)

Comment: I checked, and it's not.  The behavior described in the question still occurs.