# Join this community button does not redirect to the page you were on

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, redirection

How it *should* be:

- You click the `Join` banner button button.
- You get a confirmation `Are you sure you want to join this community?`
- Upon clicking `Create Account`, your account gets created, **and you get redirected to the page you were on**

All of the above are working, except for the bold line, i.e. I'm being redirected to the site's front page.

Example:

[image: Join animated GIF]

**EDIT:** In regard to [the proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251982), this question is different.  That one seems to be about the `join this community` button in the black SE bar, however, mine is about the `Join` button in the community banner.  Also, as an additional note, the black `join this community` button [*does* work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjE30.gif). (ie. It redirects correctly)

**EDIT 2:** Turns out it's pretty much the same problem, just a different way to get there.  I make [another animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3q9l.gif) showing *that* problem.

NOTE:  This happens on *every* SE site - I've noticed it quite a few times.

NOTE2: I'm using FF 44.0 at the moment.

Comment: If someone could test this in different browsers, and edit my question to include your findings, that'd be wonderful.  Thanks!

Comment: This bug pre-dates the "join this community" feature, and was simply never fixed

Comment: @ShadowWizard but this question is *much* easier to follow and understand...! could we make the other a dupe of this?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ not sure it's really that better. The older one is clear enough, in my opinion.

Comment: Nope, it's the same. It is all about the login losing the original question you were viewing, how you make the login is really not relevant.

Comment: If that's so, then I guess they're the same.  I must note, however, that mine *is* easier to understand....  but if that's the way it must be, I made [another animated GIF](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K3q9l.gif) with *that* problem.  If this one ends up being the duplicate, we should at least add an example to the other one :)